# FHIR Questionnaire - questions order

Tags: hl7-fhir

In my application I want to use FHIR Questionnaire resource.
On the server side I am trying to generate questionnaire with different types of questions and send it to the application where user (patient) can fill in answers and send them back.
However in some cases I would like from user to answer only specific questions of the questionnaire and not all of them. For example if questionnaire consists of two questions:

1. Do you smoke or drink alcohol?
2. Measure your heart rate.

I would like that user answers second question only if he has answered on the first question with 'yes'. The second question is skipped if he has answered 'no'.

The problem is that I do not know how to add these rules, which will tell which question is next, inside the Questionnaire resource.
I came along to some extensions like [ordinalValue](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extension-valueset-ordinalvalue.html), but I couldn't find out how/where to use them and where to define if user's answer must be equal / less / greater than some value.

*So I would like to know which extension i need to use (and how) to achieve what I've written before? Is this even possible with existing extensions or I would have to define a new one?*

I am adding simple representation (with only relevant data) of mentioned questionnaire in the JSON form:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Questionnaire",
  ...
  "item": [
    {
      "linkId": "1",
      "text": "Do you smoke or drink alcohol?",
      "type": "boolean"
      << ??? extension ???>>
    },
    {
      "linkId": "2",
      "text": "Measure your heart rate.",
      "type": "integer"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Questionnaire.item.enableWhen element for this:

```
{
    "linkId": "2",
    "text": "Measure your heart rate.",
    "type": "integer"
    "enableWhen": [{
            "question": "1",
            "answerBoolean": "true",
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have somehow misunderstood the purpose of this element and thought that it's usage wouldn't solve my problem.

However this element does not solve the issue perfectly, because when user answers some question I would like to know which question is next without searching over all other questions. It would be better to have information about next question inside the question user is currently answering.

Anyway, your solution works, so I am marking it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Questionnaire doesn't impose a notion of "next" as some data may be automatically populated into the response and some interfaces may allow a user to navigate forward and backward when filling in the form.  For your use-case, the "next" question will be the next question within the sequence of Questionnaire items that currently happens to be enabled.  If the Questionnaire is designed with this in mind, you should only have to scan forward to find the next question.

Comment: Thank you for additional info. The problem with my use-case is that in some rare cases user will also have to go backwards (lets say from question 5 to question 2). This means I still have to scan all the questions to find the right one.